# Need to extract the timestamp from a logstash elasticsearch cluster

Tags: json, parsing, elasticsearch, logstash, dsl

I'm trying to determine the freshness of the most recent record in my logstash cluster, but I'm having a bit of trouble digesting the Elasticsearch DSL.

Right now I am doing something like this to extract the timestamp: 
    curl -sX GET  'http://localhost:9200/logstash-2015.06.02/' -d'{"query": {"match_all": {} } }' | json_pp | grep timestamp

which gets me; 
    "@timestamp" : "2015-06-02T00:00:28.371+00:00",

I'd like to use an elasticsearch query directly with no grep hackiness.

The raw JSON (snipped for length) looks like this:

```
{
   "took" : 115,
   "timed_out" : false,
   "hits" : {
      "hits" : [
         {
            "_index" : "logstash-2015.06.02",
            "_source" : {
               "type" : "syslog",
               "@timestamp" : "2015-06-02T00:00:28.371+00:00",
               "tags" : [
                  "sys",
                  "inf"
               ],
               "message" : "    2015/06/02 00:00:28 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: generichost.example.com 10.1.1.10",
               "file" : "/var/log/consul.log",
               "@version" : 1,
               "host" : "generichost.example.com"
            },
            "_id" : "AU4xcf51cXOri9NL1hro",
            "_score" : 1,
            "_type" : "syslog"
         },
      ],
      "total" : 8605141,
      "max_score" : 1
   },
   "_shards" : {
      "total" : 50,
      "successful" : 50,
      "failed" : 0
   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I know the query is simple, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the DSL for this. You can simply cram everything into the [URL query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html), like this:

```
curl -s XGET 'localhost:9200/logstash-2015.06.02/_search?_source=@timestamp&size=1&sort=@timestamp:desc&format=yaml'
```

So:

- `_source=@timestamp` means we're only interested in getting the `@timestamp` value
- `size=1` means we only need one result
- `sort=@timestamp:desc` means we want to sort on `@timestamp` descending (i.e. latest first)
- `format=yaml` will get you the result in YAML format which is a bit more concise than JSON in your case

The output would look like this:

```
- _index: "logstash-2015.06.02"
  _type: "syslog"
  _id: "AU4xcf51cXOri9NL1hro"
  _score: 1.0
  _source:
    @timestamp: "2015-06-02T00:00:28.371+00:00"
```

You don't need `json_pp` anymore, you can still simply grep `@timestamp` to get the data you need.

Note that in 1.6.0, there will be a way to filter out all the metadata (i.e. `_index`, `_type`, `_id`, `_score`) and only get the `_source` for a search result using the [`filter_path` parameter](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/10980) in the URL.

Comment: And now that Elasticsearch 1.6.0 is out you can use response filtering: https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-6-0-released#response-filtering